# How to click this button with python & selenium - table

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

[url of the website](https://www.cbs.gov.il/he/Statistics/Pages/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA.aspx)

[image]

Hey all, I just wanna click this button with python
my code:

```
Main_page=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,service=chrome_service)
base_url="https://www.cbs.gov.il/he/Statistics/Pages/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA.aspx"
Main_page.get(base_url)
Main_page.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
button = Main_page.find_element(By.NAME, 'ישראל כולל יהודה ושומרון')
button.click()
```

i can figure it out why is not working

error:
oSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="ישראל כולל יהודה ושומרון"]"}
(Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.63)

Answer (score 2):

check this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/click-element-method-selenium-python/

NOTE : you can also use xpath to find elements

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='link']")
```

NOTE : you can copy xpath from any Browser
[here is how to find xpath in browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyFAM.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey , i have used the tool but still, i have an error code:   `Main_page=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,service=chrome_service)
base_url="https://www.cbs.gov.il/he/Statistics/Pages/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA.aspx"
Main_page.get(base_url)
Main_page.maximize_window()
time.sleep(15)
button = Main_page.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/div/ul/li[3]")
button.click()
`

Answer (score 2):

```py
button = Main_page.find_element(By.NAME, 'ישראל כולל יהודה ושומרון')
button.click()
```

you try to find elements by name , but `שראל כולל יהודה ושומרון` its not a valid html or xml name its an innerText of the button ,
try to find using xpath as i mentioned bef or find it by id